# Pydantic Model Field Of Type Union[int, float] : How To Prevent Field From Rounding To int When Initialised With float Value?

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

I have the following pydantic model which contains a result typed as `Union[int,float]` as listed below.

```py
from typing import Union

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Calculation(BaseModel):
    arg1: int 
    arg2: int 


class CalculationResult(Calculation):
    op: str 
    result: Union[int, float]


if __name__ == "__main__":

    arg1 = 1 
    arg2 = 2 
    result = arg1 / arg2

    # this displays type of result := <class 'float'> when program is run
    print(f"type of result := {type(result)}")

    x = CalculationResult(**{"arg1": arg1, "arg2": arg2, "op": "divide", "result": result}) 

    print(f"result := {x.result}")
```

When the result property of `CalculationResult` has a value of 0.5 it is rounded to 0.

How do I get pydantic to recognise that 0.5 is a float for the typing hint `Union[int, float]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modifying the order as mention in @anon_dcs3spp's answer may not be ideal as `Union[float, int]` would lead to all integers being coerced to floats.

Pydantic added support for `smart_union` [recently](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/model_config/#smart-union) which prevents the type-coercion and preserves original types.

So something like below, should work!

class CalculationResult(Calculation):
op: str
result: Union[int, float]

```
class CalculationResult(Calculation):
    op: str 
    result: Union[int, float]

    class Config:
       smart_union = True
```

Comment: +1 Nice! Thanks for posting this. Have just seen your answer and will accept it as the answer to my original question. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 5):

Solved after looking at Pydantic [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#unions)!

The solution is to specify the most specific type first, followed by less general types. In this case, I swapped the order of float and int in the union type declaration.

```py
class CalculationResult(Calculation):
    op: str 
    result: Union[float, int]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `float | bool`, but Harshith's answer below does